# How to add folder exceptions to exclude paths from Bitdefender Antivirus Free Edition?

Tags: path, anti-virus, exclude, exceptions, bitdefender

http://www.ghacks.net/2012/12/29/bitdefender-antivirus-free-edition-review/

I cannot find any specific way to bring up a place where I can put paths/ folders that I wish to exclude from BitDefender.

http://www.bitdefender.com/support/how-to-add-exclusions-(exceptions)-in-bitdefender-2016-1467.html

Is this not allowed in the free edition or it's hidden at some place that I cannot find.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the Program open?

Comment: @NetworkKingPin - 1st link - thats pretty much it. I cant bring up any UI except the one visible on it. - http://www.ghacks.net/2012/12/29/bitdefender-antivirus-free-edition-review/

Comment: In the Link it says the program does not allow you to add exclusions to the program as it is featureless. Why dont you get malwarebytes and use Windows Defender.  Just a Suggestion. You can add paths to exclude in both. And the Malwarebytes free and paid version are really great for windows.

Comment: @NetworkKingPin - Thanks. I was not sure, but confirmed this with their tech support. Back to one of the 3 A's Avira, AVG, Avast :( . How is Malware bytes, are they solid or just another new kid on the block

Comment: Very Solid used it for years. Never had any issues. I also use their anti exploit. They also have lifetime licences and they are pretty cheap. https://www.malwarebytes.org/ check them out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upon chatting with their Technical Support on this link:
http://www.bitdefender.com/support/chat-support.html

They do not at the moment support this or plan to in the future.

We got this answer:

> Liviu A. (12:32:18) : Ax, I would like to inform you that you can not add any exceptions on Antivirus free edition.
>
> Liviu A. (12:33:16) : The Bitdefender Antivirus free edition works as a basic scanner.

Even if there are false positives, they will not add a simple mechanism like this.

> Ax (12:33:22) : Yes, but most other Free Editions from other companies
> allow us to add exceptions
>
> Ax (12:33:46) : Exclude folders, especially since your tool is marking
> False Positives
>
> Liviu A. (12:35:31) : I understand the situation, but Bitdefender
> antivirus free does not have the option to exclude files and folders.
>
> Ax (12:35:58) : And there is no plan to change this in future.
>
> Ax (12:36:40) : ?
>
> Liviu A. (12:37:17) : Not as I am aware.
>
> Ax (12:37:14) : Thank you. That will be all.